# Layout broken in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having problems with the layout on an iOS7 device. 
On iOS8 it looks just fine but on iOS7 its broken.
Already looked around here but did not found the right answer yet. Hope anybody can help me.

iOS7:
[image]

iOS8:
[image]

Comment: The UITabBar is translucent in you iOS7 screen shot but not in your iOS8 one. Try settings the translucent property to NO.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: There are 7 differences in the photos above. Can you spot them? LOL

Comment: @Bhavin yes it is ticked "ON". Is this bad?